# how to install Google maps SDK in xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, xcode7.3

I followed the instructions provided [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#obtaining_an_api_key) by google about manually installing google maps SDK, but I have an issue:

When I right-click GoogleMaps.framework, then click show in finder, I can't find *resources* folder or *GoogleMaps.bundle*!

my environment:

- OS X El Capitan (virtual machine, using vmware)
- Xcode 7.3.1
- I am adding it to a swift project that uses story board

I did follow exactly what instructions said, and ticked "copy items if needed"

what I have done wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to install cocoapods correctly before in order to integrate google map to your project.

Steps to install cocoapods:

1. Open terminal and type: **sudo gem install cocoapods**
2. In terminal go to your project and type: **pod init** *this will create podfile inside your project*
3. In last type: **pod install**

**Note:** do not forgot to edit your `podfile` before install using [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#obtaining_an_api_key) as mentioned and use `.xcworkspace` file (*this will automatically created after install cocoapod*) to launch `Xcode` for further development.

Terminal screen will look like this if you installed cocoapods successfully, see image.

[image: Terminal screen]

for further in google map see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39179415/4003548)

Comment: I dont want to use cocoapods, because I have to upgrade ruby and this is another headache I suffered without any results. So I followed the manually installation instructions provided in google documents in the link above

Comment: In fact i have given exact solution here according to your ques with extra screen description i don't know why down voted me here ?. And the above link is also suggesting the same, upgrading ruby and other things is not on over this community.

Comment: its okay mate ..but according to me you need to install cocoapods in order to use latest version of google map, rest you find solution :)

Comment: I ended up doing that, I had troubles with updating the ruby but I solved it, and here is a vote up bro :)